# removing certain characters from entries within a list

Tags: python-3.x

I need to remove the [',\n\xa0 characters and the years (1994) from this entry in the list then iterate over the list doing this to each entry. 
is there a way I can do this? I'm newish to python and have been trying for hours

The entries are like so :

```
[['The Shawshank Redemption\n(1994)\n\n\n 9.2\xa0\xa0\n\n'], ['The Godfather\n(1972)\n\n\n 9.2\xa0\xa0\n\n'], ['The Godfather: Part II\n(1974)\n\n\n 9.0\xa0\xa0\n\n'],
```

edit: sorry for not including the code, iv managed to strip the numbers and the \n newline characters after the year. but still getting newlines character just after the film title. ill paste my code anwyway thanks!:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random

names = []
newList = []
url = 'http://m.imdb.com/chart/top'
# get contents from url
content = requests.get(url).content
# get soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') # choose lxml parser
# find all the references
ref_tags = soup.findAll('span', { 'class' : 'media-body' })
realTags = soup.find_all("h4")
# iterate through the ResultSet
for i,ref_tag in enumerate(ref_tags):
    # print text only
    names.append('[{0}] {1}'.format(i,ref_tag.text))
pos = 0
for name in names:
    newName = names[pos]
    newName = newName[9:]
    newName = newName[:100]
    newName = newName.split("(")
    newName = newName[::2]
    del newName[2:9:3]
    newList.append(newName)
    pos = pos + 1

print(newList)
choice = random.choice(newList)
print(choice)
```

the output is like this:

[['The Shawshank Redemption\n'], ['The Godfather\n'], ['The Godfather: Part II\n'], ['The Dark Knight\n'], ['12 Angry Men\n']

Comment: What have you tried exactly that did not work?

Comment: As @nbro mentions you should add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

so i got it to output how i would like. thanks any!

heres the code for anyone who may need it in future:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random

names = []
newList = []
url = 'http://m.imdb.com/chart/top'
# get contents from url
content = requests.get(url).content
# get soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml') # choose lxml parser
# find all the references
ref_tags = soup.findAll('span', { 'class' : 'media-body' })
realTags = soup.find_all("h4")
# iterate through the ResultSet
for i,ref_tag in enumerate(ref_tags):
    # print text only
    names.append('[{0}] {1}'.format(i,ref_tag.text))
pos = 0
for name in names:
    newName = names[pos]
    newName = newName[9:]
    newName = newName[:100]
    newName = newName.split("(")
    newName = newName[::2]
    del newName[2:9:3]
    newList.append(newName)
    pos = pos + 1

wordChoice = random.choice(newList)
str = str(wordChoice)
editWord = str.split("\\n")



print(editWord[1])
```

and the output is like so:

```
Shutter Island
```